# How can I found out if file is alias or symbolic link?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I'm working on a legacy system and I have a bunch of files that are referencing images that are located in other folders.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user nobody      56 Feb 10  2010 t100x100.jpg -> /home/www/virtual/categories/swm/24/m/00012/t100x100.jpg
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user nobody      56 Feb 10  2010 t100x133.jpg -> /home/www/virtual/categories/swm/24/m/00012/t100x133.jpg
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user nobody      56 Feb 10  2010 t125x150.jpg -> /home/www/virtual/categories/swm/24/m/00012/t125x150.jpg
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user nobody      56 Feb 10  2010 t150x200.jpg -> /home/www/virtual/categories/swm/24/m/00012/t150x200.jpg
```

How can I know if these are symbolic links or aliases?

Comment: A symbolic link is a file entry that references another file. In Linux, an alias is a command syntax replacement. What do you mean by an alias? Or are you simply asking how to identify which files are symbolic links? `find folder -type l` will list all symbolic links below 'folder'.

Comment: Are you asking about aliases in Mac OS X Finder, or shell command aliases?

Comment: I guess I was a bit confused. The files in question were just symbolic link and I guess I was confusing with Os X Finder aliases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Symbolic links:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user nobody      56 Feb 10  2010 t100x100.jpg -> /home/www/virtual/categories/swm/24/m/00012/t100x100.jpg
^
 ` Here it is, l for symbolic link.
```

If you files are hard links then they show up just as other files. For example every directory has directory named `.` hardlinked to it.

#### From `$ man find`:

> Each directory on a normal Unix filesystem has at least 2 hard links: its name and its `.'  entry.  Additionally, its subdirectories (if any) each have a`..'
>                 entry linked to that directory.

#### Hard links:

```
-rw-r--r--  3 root root   60 2012-06-25 12:17 File
-rw-r--r--  3 root root   60 2012-06-25 12:17 HardLinkToFile
-rw-r--r--  3 root root   60 2012-06-25 12:17 HardLinkToFile2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user nobody      56 Feb 10  2010 t100x100.jpg -> /home/www/virtual/categories/swm/24/m/00012/t100x100.jpg
            ^
             ` This number is hard link (reference) count.
```

Answer (score 12):

The `file` or `stat` commands will tell you what a file is:

```
$ ln -s /home this_is_a_link
$ touch this_is_not_a_link
$ file this_*
this_is_a_link:     symbolic link to `/home'
this_is_not_a_link: empty
$ stat this_*
  File: `this_is_a_link' -> `/home'
  Size: 5               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: ca00h/51712d    Inode: 106983      Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/    andy)   Gid: ( 1000/    andy)
Access: 2012-07-29 23:28:17.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2012-07-29 23:28:17.000000000 +0000
Change: 2012-07-29 23:28:17.000000000 +0000
  File: `this_is_not_a_link'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: ca00h/51712d    Inode: 106992      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    andy)   Gid: ( 1000/    andy)
Access: 2012-07-29 23:28:27.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2012-07-29 23:28:27.000000000 +0000
Change: 2012-07-29 23:28:27.000000000 +0000
```

If scripting, the `test` command may be of more use:

> ```
>    -h FILE
>          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
> ```

```
$ for f in this_*; do if test -h "$f"; then echo "$f is a symlink"; else echo "$f is not a symlink"; fi; done
this_is_a_link is a symlink
this_is_not_a_link is not a symlink
```